# How to create a Graph with ggpredict

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try to use `ggpredict` like my professor, she keeps getting a graph but when I do it all I get is numbers.
I have `ggeffects`, `ggplot2`, `rgl` and `devtools` installed.

```
mod_p1q1 <- lm(fem_leg_pct ~ adult_literacy, data = dat)
summary(mod_p1q1)

ggpredict(mod_p1q1,
          show.text = FALSE)
```

this is the code I used.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(dat)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(dat, 20))`.

Comment: Try checking out the help in `help("ggpredict")`. Especially the example section. `plot(ggpredict(mod_p1q1, show.text = FALSE))` is what you are looking for (most likely)